# Ionic 2 floating ion-labels issue

Tags: html, mobile, ionic2

I'm having an issue with *some* of the floating labels that I'm using but not all of them, which makes it even stranger. As far as I can see my ion-items are written exactly the same. Below are some pictures to show the issue.
I'm not sure whether this is a bug in Ionic 2 or if I'm doing something wrong. If there's anything unclear or you need more code, feel free to ask.

As you can see, the *description* and *photo/video* label are already acting like they should when they're in focus (they're not) but it's not displaying the highlights.

[image: Problem 1]

Here is an image where I put it in focus and then out of focus again.
Once I do that it works correctly.

[image: Problem 2]

The html I wrote:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <form [formGroup]="complaint" (ngSubmit)="send()">

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Description*</ion-label>
      <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="description" type="text" formControlName="description"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Number of completed tests*</ion-label>
      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="nrTests" type="number" formControlName="nrTests"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Photo/Video</ion-label>
      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="media" formControlName="media"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <button ion-button type="submit" [disabled]="!complaint.valid">Send</button>

  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Can you simulate it here?:http://embed.plnkr.co/SJ8GtqbRntby5yGzLEft/

Comment: I'm not familiar with plunker but i put my code in it (rapport). Maybe you can make it work

Comment: What happens if you add an `ion-list` tag inside the form, and place all the `ion-item` elements inside of that `ion-list`?

Comment: did you manange to simulate it ?

Comment: The ion-list doesn't work either. No, I didn't manage to simulate it, where do I have to put my code? In page1.ts?

Comment: can you put it on git repo and also a small video about the behavior also useful?

Comment: i'll put it on github

Comment: [Here's the git repo](https://github.com/nickbleyen/floatinglabels/blob/master/src/pages/home/home.html) I put the rapport code in the home tab here as I don't think I'm allowed to share the whole thing.

Comment: Can't you put a working copy of it? Just create a blank ionic2 project and put your code there.Then we just need to do `ionic serve` no? And also when you put a comment try to mention the name of the recipient like this @NickBleyen

Comment: You can do that now too. It worked for me anyway let me take a look

Comment: Ok I see, when I made a git repository from my folder it didn't take the plugins, modules,..

Comment: Here's a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VbXrhOjnlfHfXDpqOkd0?p=preview) with your form but I can't reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `floating` and then try. I think this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use stacked attribute to the ionic label and use the ion-item with in the ion-list.